# How to use wicket StringResourceModel in downloadLink

Tags: java, wicket

I have button which works:

```
    Button options = new Button("sheets", new StringResourceModel("sheets", null)) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onSubmit() {
            setResponsePage(new TournamentOptionsPage(tournament, table) {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            });
        }
    };
```

now I want to replace this button with downloadLink:

```
        add(new DownloadLink("sheets", new AbstractReadOnlyModel<File>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public File getObject() {
                File tempFile;
                try {
                    tempFile = PdfFactory.createSheets(WicketApplication.getSheetsPath(),
                            tournamentService.getSchedule(table, tournament), table);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                return tempFile;
            }
        }, new StringResourceModel("sheets", null)).setCacheDuration(Duration.NONE).setDeleteAfterDownload(true));
```

but here I have problem with StringResourceModel and when I push link I got exception:

```
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Unable to find property: 'sheets'
    at org.apache.wicket.Localizer.getString(Localizer.java:239)
    at org.apache.wicket.Localizer.getString(Localizer.java:170)
    at org.apache.wicket.model.StringResourceModel.getString(StringResourceModel.java:425)
    at org.apache.wicket.model.StringResourceModel.getString(StringResourceModel.java:400)
    at org.apache.wicket.model.StringResourceModel.load(StringResourceModel.java:583)
    at org.apache.wicket.model.StringResourceModel.load(StringResourceModel.java:182)
    at org.apache.wicket.model.LoadableDetachableModel.getObject(LoadableDetachableModel.java:119)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.DownloadLink.onClick(DownloadLink.java:151)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.Link.onLinkClicked(Link.java:188)
```

Why this doesnt work ?

Comment: quick reply: you haven't defined your property "sheets" anywhere, that's why it can't find it.

Comment: yea and why in button it works ? I have defined it in properties file which I didnt upload here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've opened an issue to discuss this problem

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-4738

Comment: Yes. My patch has been accepted but we should wait for the next release to have the fix.

Comment: ok thx a lot. I hope they release new version as soon as possible :)

Comment: Hi again. I hope your are still tuned. I see this issue is fixed so I try it again. I change to version 1.5.9 but still with negative result :(. I try new StringResourceModel("sheets", this, null), new StringResourceModel("sheets", null) and new ResourceModel("sheets") nothing works :(

Comment: ok I got it. Now name of the file is localize. Problem is I dont want it. I want localize label of download link what still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why Button works but DownloadLink doesn't. Anyway you could solve your problem passing the container component to StringResourceModel. Something like this should be ok:

```
new StringResourceModel("sheets", this,null)
```

Comment: hm this code solve exception but link still isnt translated and name of file name is override to "sheets"

Comment: Where does the bundle come from? I mean, where is the properties file? Is it defined for the  container of the link?

Comment: I follow this example to create localization pages: http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/pub2/?0 so properties file in the same folder as html and java file

Comment: It seems a bug with DownloadLink. If I'm right I will open an issue on Wicket issue tracker.

Comment: BTW, what is the final result you want to obtain? What do you mean when you say that link "still isn't translated"?

Comment: I have application which support 2 language. English and Slovak. So when I change language to SVK I want use label which I define in svk properties. This works in other component as Label Button ... just downloadLink has problem with this